# 2 ScrolledComposite side by side.

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp

I'm building a welcome editor for my eclipse rcp application. I want to have two ScrolledComposites sit side by side with a label above each.

```
Label 1             Label 2

Scrollable 1        Scrollable 2
```

Now I'm stuck in how to box.

This seems right but now I can't get the layouts and listeners right.

- Composite A

  - Composite A1

    - Label 1
    - Scrollable S1
  - Composite A2

    - Label 2
    - Scrollable S2

A1 should set the min Size of Scrollable S1 right? But who sets the size of S1 so that it fills the excess space? The examples I found didn't work right.

BTW putting everything in a GridLayout didn't work either since I couldn't get the cell size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> BTW putting everything in a GridLayout didn't work either since I couldn't get the cell size.

Why would you need the cell size? Just set `GridLayoutdata` for `S1` and `S2` to fill the cell. It's simplest to use [`GridLayoutFactory`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjface%2Flayout%2FGridLayoutFactory.html):

```
import org.eclipse.jface.layout.GridLayoutFactory;

...
GridLayoutFactory.fillDefaults().applyTo(s1);
GridLayoutFactory.fillDefaults().applyTo(s2);
...
```

UPDATE: See examples at http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/custom/ScrolledComposite.html

Let's say content of `s1` is a `Composite c1`. Then you use `s1.setMinSize(c1.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT))`. Size of `A1` is irrelevant.

Comment: I'll try it again then. But thinking about it I still have a knot in my brain. I thought size is the actual size of the scroll area and min size the size of the container.

Comment: On my first try I obviously hadn't got FILL_BOTH set. #-)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [SWT Snippet](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/) for "[fixed first column horizontal scroll remaining columns](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet234.java)" - although this example is for `Tables`, it can easily be translated to  `ScrolledComposites`.